# Find the line that it starts a custom py script file

Tags: linux, ssh, python, raspberry-pi

A while ago I somehow managed to make an executable file start a startup.

Unfortunately, I don't remember how I did that.

What I remember is that I created a custom executable file which is calling a py file.

Now I can see that this file runs only and if only I log in via ssh to my raspberry pi. If no ssh session (login) is open the script, it won't run.

Well this is what I need to fix now, to run without the need of ssh-ing to it. But fist of all I have to delete the current startup line.

I checked the rc.local, crontab -e but there is no such a line.

From the details I gave you, any other places I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be started by your shell upon login. Check the configuration files of your shell.

This will be most likely `bash`. So check the following files: `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.

## EDIT:

You could check the Parent Pid of your Process and see what has started your py file.

You find the Parent Pid by looking at the output of `ps o pid,ppid,comm`.

```
user@host:~ ps o pid,ppid,comm
  PID  PPID COMMAND
26071 26046 bash
26103 26071 yes
27138 26071 ps
```

Here the command yes is started by bash. Another option to visualize is `pstree`.

```
user@host:~ pstree
systemd─┬─2*[abrt-watch-log]
        ...
        ├─sshd───sshd───sshd───bash─┬─pstree
        │                           └─yes
        ...
```

What does your output look like?

Comment: It appears to be none of them, Jonas. Thanks for your reply though.